# Bootstrapping TestServer with TestStartup with InMemoryDatabase fails (.Net core)

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Perhaps I've missed something, or perhaps something is broken. I hope to find out what happens here.

TLDR: Bootstrapping a `TestServer` class with an InMemory database, gives 
`(No service for type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.IRelationalConnection' has been registered)`. Any clues? More details below:

I have a test class, which uses a TestFixture to bootstrap:

```
public AccountControllerTest(TestServerFixture testServerFixture) : base(testServerFixture)
    {
    }
```

The testServerFixture looks like this:
public class TestServerFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public TestServer server { get; }

```
    public HttpClient client { get; }

    public TestServerFixture()
    {
        // Arrange
        var builder = TestServer.CreateBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseStartup<TestPortalStartup>()
            .UseServices(services =>
            {
                // Change the application environment to the mvc project
                var env = new TestApplicationEnvironment();
                env.ApplicationBasePath =
                    Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "..", "MY_APP"));
                env.ApplicationName = "MY_APP";
                //SUPER IMPORTANT: Should be the real application name, else you'll get Roslyn Compiler Errors in your views

                services.AddInstance<IApplicationEnvironment>(env);
            });

        server = new TestServer(builder);

        client = server.CreateClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        server.Dispose();
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And as you can see it uses a `TestPortalStartup` which looks like this:
public class TestPortalStartup : Startup
    {
        private Mock accountRegistrationClientMock;

```
    public TestPortalStartup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv) : base(env, appEnv)
    {
    }

    public override void SetUpDataBaseAndMigrations(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
          .AddEntityFramework()
          .AddInMemoryDatabase()
          .AddDbContext<CmsDbContext> (
            options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase()
        );
    }


    public override void AddFrameworkDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    // ... not relevant
    }

}
```

As you can see in the `SetUpDataBaseAndMigrations` we bootstrap an `InMemoryDatabase` and a `DbContext`.

I have used this construct before to test a Service that deals with the Database. (but this is isolated).

Now with an integration test I end up failing to bootstrap the test with:

> Result StackTrace:   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1
>   accessor)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalConnection(DatabaseFacade
>   databaseFacade)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetDbConnection(DatabaseFacade
>   databaseFacade)    at
>   MY_APP.Portal.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in
>   MY_APP/Startup.cs:line 175 Result Message:  One or more errors
>   occurred. No service for type
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.IRelationalConnection' has been
>   registered. The following constructor parameters did not have matching
>   fixture data: TestServerFixture testServerFixture

In case you wonder what happens at `MY_APP/Startup.cs` (line 175) that is:

```
 logger.LogInformation($"Using SQL Connection: {dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().DataSource}");
```

Running with a 'normal' database (ie, not an In memory one) will PASS the test.

So it looks like some dependencies/wiring is missing? Anyone has experience with this? Clues? etc.

Comment: Using a Sqlite instead of inMemory seems to work. Although this is not what I wanted. So question remains open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I posted this question at the AspDotNet github, the answer was that the InMemoryDatabase from EntityFramework itself is not meant to do integration testing like this.

An alternative is using SQLite - but then also in memory mode.

Since creating all this (from scratch to fully working integration tests) took me quite some time to figure out. I figured I would summerise this all in a blog post:

http://www.stefanhendriks.com/2016/04/29/integration-testing-your-dot-net-core-app-with-an-in-memory-database/

Comment: the blog is updated to .net core 1.0 - I can see many people coming from stackoverflow - I hope it is useful!

Comment: Would be great if you formated code on your blog post

Comment: @Cubelaster thanks for pointing it out, it had code formatting but got broken. Fixed!